Next.js 14 gives 403 for specific routes (hosted on AWS/Cloudfron/Serverless)
I have a Next.js v.14 application hosted on AWS/Cloudfront. The issue is that certain dynamic routes give 403 in the browser. I am using SSR, and the pre-rendering for these pages work well, the HTMLs are created. On localhost the app works, the issue is on the server, when the app gets deployed. This error is not thrown on other dynamic routes, just a couple of them (ex: /events/[event]).
The below is the 403 error in the browser.
I would like to figure out that this error is from the server (Cloudfront, AWS etc) or from the Next.js application? And furthermore I would like to solve this issue, any idea would be appreciated.
Thank you!
The 403 screen
What I tried so far:

renaming the path seems to work, but I dont want to do that, because I need that specific path (events)
creating further slugs in the problematic routes will show 403 as well (ex: events/[event]/[anything])
I dont have any other /events or /events/[event] path in the application
other dynamic routes work as expected
I am using an API that does not have auth set up, and I also tried to remove the API call, and still the issue persists
I am using generateStaticParams and the pages get pre-rendered at build time as expected
the API is used on other parts of the application without problem

